# Is it a bad practice to write a lot of type aliases?

Tags: c++

I find myself writing a lot of type aliases (typedefs) to make code more easy to change but at the same time something tells me to avoid doing it because it can create a lot of confusion for people who are going to work with/on my code.

Perhaps not the best of examples but take a look [here](https://github.com/zoopp/polynomial/blob/master/source/polynomial.h). I'll also give a more recent example; these are some classes I fiddled around while building an XML parser:

```
namespace XML
{
    struct Attribute
    {
        typedef std::string name_t;
        typedef std::string value_t;

        Attribute(const name_t &name, const value_t &value = "");

        name_t name;
        value_t value;
    };
}

namespace XML
{
    class Element
    {
        private:
            typedef std::list<Attribute> attribute_container;
            typedef std::list<Element> element_container;

        public:
            typedef attribute_container::iterator attribute_iterator;
            typedef attribute_container::const_iterator const_attribute_iterator;

            typedef element_container::iterator element_iterator;
            typedef element_container::const_iterator const_element_iterator;

            typedef std::string name_t;
            typedef std::string data_t;
...
        private:
            name_t _name;
            data_t _data;

            attribute_container _attributes;
            element_container _child_elements;
```

Doing things this way makes it easier to write code and perhaps it makes it somewhat intuitive but what are the downsides of such a practice?

Comment: It adds a level of indirection, so that people reading your code will have to look at two things instead of just one. Is it really worth it? Experienced C++ developers will instantly recognize `std::list<Attribute>`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, but the other side is if the code ever wants to use a different container, everywhere that created an iterator on the container will need to be changed (as an example).

Comment: If it is helpful it is good otherwise it is bad.  The rub is knowing the difference.  Aliasing a string, for instance, would just annoy me.

Comment: On the pro side: it help when refactoring big amounts of code

Comment: I would name it `attribute_sequence`, but yes, in general I would consider this sort of typedef'ing A Good Thing.  Additional semantic information is often helpful, and it helps keep your code DRY:  if you want to swap `list` out for `vector`, you need only change it in one place.

Comment: I voted to close this question. It's basically a question about programming style, so I don't think it's constructive.

Comment: @PaulManta Can't vote but disagree. It's a design question not programming style, typedefs are part of class or package design!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effective programming is all about what you can fit into your head. If defining a type makes it easier to fit into your head, go for it. But if you do too much, the cognitive load of keeping track of too many types will hurt you overall.

For example I might use one for this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > SynonymMap;
```

Taken to its conclusion, you'd be inventing a new type for each variable in your program. How readable would that be?

Comment: Good point! Creating a type for each new variable isn't really a good thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

Here are my 5 cents. You simply have to make those typedefs in certain situation. For example, if you are writing your own iterator class, you have to make it work with `iterator_traits` and provide nested typedefs like `difference_type` etc. The same applies for containers in some cases. For example, if some common function is written like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T::iterator it);
```

then whatever `T` is specified as template argument, it must have a nested `iterator` type declared. You may throw in extra template interface conventions of your own and follow them throughout the code.

Another case where nested types are useful is to alias a template argument to let other parts of the code refer to it. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  public:
    typedef T now_you_can_access_this_from_the_outside;
};
```

But other than that — typedefing is not required. Then it is a matter of preference, but I bet my house on it — `std::string` is more readable than `value_t` simply because everybody knows what `std::string` is, and `value_t` tells nothing about itself.

Answer (score 3):

My rule of thumb is if typedef is used more than 2-3 times, then it is worth existing.
Otherwise, this is wast of ink, which is bad for environment.

Comment: I imagine it would decrease development speed quite a bit. :P

Comment: @KirillKobelev you just made my day :)

Comment: @KirillKobelev: Thx for the edit — idk why other guys have rejected it. There seem to be no way to unreject, so I put that in myself.

Answer (score 2):

Subjectively when done right this actually makes code easier to read and understand. Also in `std` and by extension `boost` this is used extensively, so you might want to do it just to stay consistent.